# How to pass params for Vend Api?

Tags: json, api, curl

I am trying to use VEND API but I have no clue how to pass parameters for doing various things. I found a set of codes in the API doc but can't get through it. Below is what I been up to.

```
<?php
/**
*
* A class made for utility methods around Vend's API
*
*
*/
class VendApiUtils {

/**
* A simple static method to call Vend API urls
*
* @param string $url
* @param string $username
* @param string $password
* @param array $params <OPTIONAL>
*/
public static function requestVendApiUrl($url, $username, $password, $params = array())
{
// is cURL installed?
if (!function_exists('curl_init')) {

throw new Exception('CURL is not installed!');
}

// Create a new cURL instance
$ch = curl_init();

$opts = array(
CURLOPT_URL => $url,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_POST => 1,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('data' => json_encode($params)),
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,
CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => 1,
CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_ANY, 
CURLOPT_USERPWD => "$username:$password" 
);

// Assign the cURL options
curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);

// Get the response
$response = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($response);

// Close cURL
curl_close($ch);

// Execute the request & get the response
echo $response;
}
}


$your_domain='https://mydomain.vendhq.com';
$your_username='myuser'; 
$your_password='mypass';
$params = array('GET'=>'/api/stock_movements');
$response =  VendApiUtils::requestVendApiUrl($your_domain, $your_username,$your_password, $params);

//echo $response;
?>
```

Any Help would be highly appreicated.

Regards,
Abnab

Comment: Your question is not very clear - what does "pass parameters for doing various things" mean? What is it you are trying to pass, from where, to where, and why are you having difficulty doing it?

Comment: @IMSoP Thanks for your reply. I am trying to pass requests through params variable. Requests like getting stock from Vend or item detail. I found this piece of code in the VEND API forum but it doesnt cleary say how to pass values to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you think the URL needs to go into the `$params` array; that looks to me like the place for, well, params. I think the function is intended to be used more like this:

```
// Fixed parts, same for any request
$domain='https://mydomain.vendhq.com';
$username='myuser'; 
$password='mypass';

// Variable parts, depending on what you want to do
$url = '/api/stock_movements';
$params = array('some_key' => 'some_value');

$response = VendApiUtils::requestVendApiUrl($domain . $url, $username, $password, $params);
```

Comment: Hi ,
Thanks for your answer. May be issue is at my end. I don't seem to get any output at all. No matter if I send a get or POST request there is not output at all. But if I paste the URL on to a browser directly there are results. I was trying this code from the link below.

http://support.vendhq.com/entries/20954742-Simple-PHP-cURL-Example

Answer (score 0):

Please check [pyvend](https://github.com/aselivanov/pyvend) client library.